# ClickListener doesn't work

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I've some trouble for an unknown reason in Java LibGDX scene2dui.
I've this code:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    stage  = new Stage();
    //blablabla...
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", textButtonStyle);

    exitButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            System.out.print("EXITTTTTTTT");
            //Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    });
    //blabla...
}
```

I don't know why, but java gives me a compilation error on the `@Override` annotation:

```
java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I set my java compiler in Javac 1.6 (but maybe there are other settings for the project?)
If I comment out the annotation it compiles but does nothing on click.

EDIT:
I checked the import, it's OK for the badlogic inputEvent.
My class "implements" screen". Maybe I should "extends"?

Comment: Does the class that contains this code extend another class? If so, does that class have a `show()` method?

Comment: Which Override causes the compiler error? On `show()` or `clicked()`? Are you sure you are importing the correct classes? For `show()` you need to `extend Screen`.

Comment: Probably `java.awt.event.InputEvent` instead of `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Thanks a lot for your help.
The comment of Chase is the right answer for my problem.
It's a little idiot, but I've import:

```
java.awt.event.InputEvent
```

instead of:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent
```

Ty to all!